# How to synchronised horizontal scrolling of two collection view with different cell width?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have to collection view with different cell width but equal number of cell. let say collectionview cell is equal to screen width and other collectionview cell width is about 60 pixel.
What I want is when I scoll Larger cell large cell collectionView small collectionview also scroll with respect to its content of set.
What I have tried so far is

```
func updateColoredView(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){

    let scrollX = (screenWidth) / 60.0
    
    if ((scrollView.contentOffset.x) / scrollX) < 16{
       smallCollectionView.contentOffset.x = 16.0
    }else{
        smallCollectionView.contentOffset.x = ((scrollView.contentOffset.x) / scrollX)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite clear... you have CV-A with 10 cells (each screen width) and CV-B with 10 cells (each 60-pts width). When you scroll CV-A to the 3rd cell, you want CV-B to scroll to the 3rd cell?

Comment: @DonMag This was like if i scroll CV-A  10p than CV-B should also Scroll accordingly with respect to CV-B cell width. All though I solved this one with help of content offset.